# How do OSes keep themselves from crashing when I stack overflow?

Tags: c, operating-system, stack-overflow

What methods do operating systems use to prevent crashes or erratic behavior when one of my programs accidentally leaks memory or stack overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly: Memory management.

Typically each process is allocated a limited (but usually adjustable) amount of stack space, so a single process can't use up enough to cause problems for the system as a whole.

And if a process attempts to access memory outside what's been allocated for it, that will (at worst) crash the process itself; this frees up the resources allocated for that process without stepping on other processes.

Comment: On the other hand, something like [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) can exhaust system resources -- though systems may impose per-use limits as well as per-process limits.

Answer (score 2):

OSes don´t generally protect from memory leaks in your program; but once your application ends all its memory is reclaimed. If your application never ended, then the OS would eventually get into trouble when it runs out of memory.

Regarding stack overflows, they can detect that you have gone through your stack size. A posibility is to flag a few pages after the stack as protected memory, if you try to access it then you will get a segfault and your program will be terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Very good question, thanks for asking. There are three issues that I can think of off the bat. And, for each issue, there are two cases.

**Stack overflows:** If your program is written in anything but assembly language, the OS can detect stack overflow because all stack operations are *software operations*. The run-time system manages the software stack and knows when overflow happens.

If you have taken the trouble to write your program in assembly language and you pop the *hardware stack* in error, well, the OS can't save you. Bad things can happen.

**Out-of-bounds memory accesses:** When your C++ program starts, the OS sets memory bounds on your behalf into the CPU. If your program tries to access memory outside those bounds, the CPU raises a *hardware interrupt*. The OS, as it handles the interrupt, can tell you that your program has misbehaved. This is what happens when you try to dereference a NULL pointer, for example.

Your assembly-language program, though, can try to read or write from/into whatever memory it feels like. If your program is polite and was started by the OS in the usual way, then the OS can catch that error. But if your program is evil and somehow started outside the purview of the OS, it can do some real damage.

**Memory Leaks:** Sorry, nobody can help you here.

Comment: I think you're wrong, as long as the language is compiled into executable code, there is no difference for the OS between C, C++ or assembly language. For managed languages (as those on .NET), you could be right.

Neither something written in assembly can do any harm to the OS, until it runs in user-mode, not the kernel-mode.

Both the problems you describe are detected by page faults, memory bounds are something belonging to a time long, long ago.

Comment: @Flavius -- Thanks for your very thoughtful comment: +1 for that. I'll edit the answer today to make clearer what I mean, which is that a compiled C program has to call the run-time to do anything: that restraint is compiled into the program. But an ASM program isn't necessarily restricted by such a common-sense rule. Same with user mode vs. kernel mode: a compiled C program finds it difficult to run in kernel mode, whereas an ASM program (running outside the run time) has an easier job raising its privileges. Thanks again.

Comment: I probably don't get you completely: as for the calling run-time to "do anything": for raising stack you can just recursively call some function and there is no runtime check against any value - you get the stack overflow through the paging mechanism.
In C i can pretty well do ((void (*)(void)) 0x12345678)() to jump on some weird address or acces *(void *) 0x12345678 to read the data from there, as well as in ASM.
Maybe we don't understand ourselves, but what do you mean by the "run-time"? Libraries linked to the program or something more?

Comment: @Flavius -- I mean, for windows, crt0. Every OS has something similar.

Comment: crt0 performs just some initialization, it does not limit the code executed by the app. Well, there's probably no need to follow with this discussion - as long as the code is compiled into executable machine instructions, the safety mechanisms must be and are the same. There has been some research about verification of the executable code (or inserting runtime checks into it), but it's not currently used in major operating systems.